# How to password-protect a file with Adobe Reader X?

Tags: passwords, adobe-reader

Is it possible to create a password for a file on Adobe Reader X?

Answer (score 4):

With the Adobe Reader, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

As other's have said, you cannot password protect with Adobe Reader. However, programs such as PrimoPDF (Freeware) can do this for you.

http://www.primopdf.com/

Comment: Thanks for that! to save time to others: just drop you pdf into the primo-pdf icon (no need to lunch it after configuring..)

Answer (score 0):

See this video..

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/acrobat-tips-and-tricks/protecting-your-pdf-using-a-password/

A lot depends on what version of Acrobat you are using.

On Acrobat 8 Pro, you select File->Properties and under Security tab,
select Security Method from dropdown list to be "Password Security."  A new
dialog opens that allows you to determine the options as to what will be
secure regarding the document:  does it require a password just to open it?
or can it be opened, but no changes/copying/printing allowed.  You set all
that up, enter the password and confirm that entry, and it's done when you
save that document.

With other (earlier) versions of Acrobat, the command for setting passord
is still under the File menu (it might read Document Properties or Document
Security) and the interface is basically the same with respect to setting
options.

Comment: ) but there is not option in Document Properties or Document Security all r hidden

Comment: What version are you using?.

Comment: )Adobe reader X latest

Comment: @poter You can't create PDFs with the reader version, and therefore, cannot create a password with it.

Answer (score 0):

That's odd. With Adobe Reader X, I make PDF's all the time! For password protect, go to prepare, encrypt, and follow prompts for password.

Answer (score 0):

There's a work around for not being able to password protect in Adobe Reader XI. You can "print" the document to OneNote, save the OneNote page was a Word doc, and password protect the Word doc under File > Info > Protect Document. Not an elegant solution, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: What does *Adobe Reader XI* have to do with the version the author is using ( **Adobe Reader X** )? Of course this is a general feature missing from any version of *Adobe Reader*.